# What would happen if a Tesla Coil arcs and touches a nearby 120V AC outlet?

Tags: ac, short-circuit, tesla-coil

I have a Tesla Coil that looks like this:

[image: Tesla Coil]

If this operated very closely to an AC Outlet, and an arc emerged and touched the outlet, what would happen? Would the unit short-circuit and explode? Would it create a temporary connection only to stop thereafter?

Comment: Nothing special.

Comment: What a nice looking unit.   Would be nice to have it's name, or a link to the image source.

Comment: Joytech Bluetooth Music Tesla Coil Arc Plasma Loudspeaker Wireless Transmission Experiment Desktop Toy Model SSTC SS02 https://a.co/d/4qqUzAX

Answer (score 1):

Probably not much (still not safe though), the most likely point that the arc would connect would be ground.

If the arc went to neutral not much would happen either, since it's tied to ground down the line anyway.

If it touched hot bad things could happen, it depends on the isolation of the HV transformer. It looks like one end of the coil is connected to the pin in the middle and the other to the plate around the pin. So probably nothing would happen. But if the arc touched hot, it would light the whole plate and pin up to 120V (or 220V) and connect it to the grid. Seeing how the whole thing is isolated from HV, its probably not going to do anything to connect it to 120 or 220V. But best not to find out and not safe.

The other problem is other devices on the line, some devices have MOV's or line filters that are built to either block or trip a device if a high voltage condition (think lightining) is reached. Some devices are not, so you could potentially fry something else on the line. Again not a good idea, not safe.

Comment: If your home has arc-fault circuit interrupters they may or may not detect the arc fault, and interrupt the circuit.

Answer (score 0):

The Tesla coil produces a high voltage of about 50 kilovolt but the current is small, only some milliampere or less. The AC outlet has only 120 volt but can deliver a current of some ampere, much more than the Tesla coil.

Therefore the arc from the coil could not lift the voltage of the outlet very much, the current is much too low for a large change.

A high current from the outlet could not flow back over the arc to the Tesla coil, the outlet voltage is too small for an arc of this length.

But there is no guarantee that an electronic device connected to the same circuit as the outlet could not be damaged by the arc.